# Artikel für ein englisches Wort?

Tags: definite-article, proper-noun

Welcher bestimmte Artikel sollte man für englische Wörter benutzen?  Zum Beispiel, ich möchte "The Toolchain" sagen.  Es gibt schon "die Werkzeugkette", aber "The Toolchain" ist ein Eigenname.  Benutzt man 'das' in diesem Fall?

Comment: If your question is not answered elsewhere, then please give an example of a sentence in which you would use the article in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is for example a name for a company, you would use "das". If you call a person that name, you would use the gender of the person; same with things. But I would prefer not to use an article if you are talking about a company or a product.

Comment: How can I not use an article? For instance, "I downloaded 'The Toolchain'".  Would I say "Ich habe (the,den,das,die) Toolchain heruntergeladen?"

Comment: I would say "Ich habe Toolchain" heruntergeladen" if it is an application or "Ich habe das Toolchain" heruntergeladen if it is a file but I think that there is no rule.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a name, you'd most probably stick with the English word.

Comment: I have flagged this for not being an answer, but that was because I had misread the question, my apologies. Still, the answer could be clearer.